# Unable to load classes from my gem to my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have some common code that I want to share between couple of my rails app.

I've generated my gem like so :

```
bundle gem document-common
```

My gemspec looks like so :

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'document_common/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "document_common"
  spec.version       = DocumentCommon::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ['Author']
  spec.email         = ['test@domain.com']

  spec.summary       = 'Common Models and Lib'
  spec.description   = 'Common Models and Lib'
  spec.homepage      = 'google.com'
  spec.license       = 'WTFPL'

  spec.files      = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
  spec.test_files = Dir["spec/**/*"]
  spec.test_files.reject! { |file| file.match(/[.log|.sqlite3]$/) }

  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.11"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

In my lib folder I have this :

```
document_common
document_common.rb
```

Folder `document_common` and ruby file `document_common.rb`, and the ruby file has this content :

```
require 'document_common/version'

module DocumentCommon
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

Then inside `document_common` there is a `version.rb` with this content :

```
module DocumentCommon
  VERSION = '0.1.0'
end
```

And `document.rb` with this content:

```
module DocumentCommon
  class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
end
```

So I push this gem to my git repo. And then I add this gem info to my Gemfile in the rails 4 app do a bundle install, but when I refer to `DocumentCommon::Document` I get this error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant DocumentCommon::Document
```

However if I retrieve the info about the version `DocumentCommon::VERSION` I get no errors and get the actual version. Also when I do `DocumentCommon.constants` I get `[:VERSION]`. What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to have access in my main rails app to `DocumentCommon::Document` model?

Comment: because DocumentCommon is a module I think you need to include or extend it.  http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Comment: @ruby_newbie where do I need to include it? When I try to refer to `DocumentCommon::Document` I get an error.

Comment: include it wherever you are using it.  You may only have to refer to it as Document if the module is included.  What is the stack trace for the error you are getting?

Comment: Take a look at Rails' autoloading mechanism. If your gem defines a Railtie, autoloading should work as expected, i.e. your model will be on the autoload path. Alternatively, require all the needed files in your `document_common.rb` since this file will automatically be required by bundler.

Comment: @ruby_newbie if I do include DocumentCommon::Document nothing can be found that is the issue here. I can't even refer to it let alone include it

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue today while trying to create a new gem. Feeling like a crazy person trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the autoload, check out the devise gem does exactly that:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb